# RaspberryPi not booting error:Failed to load rescue target

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, reboot

Previously my Pi4 2GB was working fine for months. After trying to get InfluxDB (a time series Database) working I rebooted my Pi. When the sreen turned back on i was greeted with the usual 4 Raspberrys, after 2 or 3 seconds an error came up. It said "Failed to load rescue target". After that nothing happens and it just stays that way.

Comment: Do you have another card that you could try a new copy of the OS on?  Where you using NOOBs, Raspbian directly or another operating system?

Comment: I was using NOOBS, i then tried with a fresh install of NOOBS but that is just giving me the Colorful Screen and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got it now.
The Solution after installing NOOBS from Scratch is to use the HDMI port closest to the USB-C port.
The other port the one further away just outputs the "colourful" screen.
I do not know why that works, but at least it does now.

Comment: Until the full O/S is booted the Pi defaults to HDMI 0 for output only - this is the one closest to the USB-C port...  Its better to drop NOOBs and load the OS direct to the SD card from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ or if you need help use the new Pi imager from the same page.